# Dynamically generating columns when summarizing PowerShell objects to the console

Tags: powershell

I have got this PowerShell cmdlet that returns zero or more custom objects; each object returned has got a `Type`, `ID` and `Status` property, so sending the cmdlet's output to the console will result in something like this:

```
Type      ID      Status
----      --      ------
Foo       1       Active
Foo       3       Active
Baz       1       Inactive
Baz       2       Active
Baz       3       Broken
Bar       4       Active
```

Using PowerShell formatting files, I'm trying to produce the following output instead:

```
ID    Foo     Baz       Bar
--    ---     ---       ---
1     Active  Inactive  
2             Active
3     Active  Broken
4                       Active
```

Is this possible at all? Grouping the items by ID seems straighforward, but I haven't got a clue as to how I can dynamically generate the columns for each `Type`?

Please note that I cannot make any changes to the cmdlet's output type since that would break other cmdlets that I might want to pipe the output to - that's why I believe a solution should ideally only involve formatting.

**EDIT**
Another way of thinking about this problem might be: "can you use PowerShell formatting files to print a kind of footer after the last item from the pipeline has been processed?" I guess this assumes that the processing of each individual item could somehow buffer that item, and that the footer could then be built using a script block that summarizes the buffered items.

Comment: You would need to use `group-object` to collect the id's and then loop through each group. The other thing you need to do ahead of time is collect all of the types so you know how many properties you are making. Is there _any_ attempt you made to try and get this to work?

Comment: Thanks for your response, @Matt! I know how to achieve the desired results by piping the output to other (built-in) PowerShell cmdlets to reshape my data - I think that's what you are referring to? Is that something one can also do from *inside* a PowerShell formatting file (.Format.ps1xml) somehow?

To rephrase what I'm after:

    MyCmdlet # sends *summarized* (see original question) output to the console; 

    MyCmdlet | SomeOtherCmdlet # same old objects as before are sent down the pipeline

Comment: @JanHoek don't rely on the 'default' output for displaying data, if you need to add 'dummy' columns I believe `Select-Object` will do it if they're explicitly named?

Comment: I must have skipped over _Using PowerShell formatting files.._ I don't think that is what ps1xml files are for but I might be wrong. I think you lost me on your explanation but let me try to rephrase. Are you just saying that you do not want to change the original data because it is required as input for another cmdlet? Do you have control between those cmdlets? So you could save the results in a variable and send the massaged results to console and original results to the next step? You could maybe get use out of tee-object for this as well

Comment: @Matt Sorry for any confusion! :-) From what I understood, formatting files can be used to fundamentally change the appearance of the output without affecting the actual objects (e.g. in the case of Get-ChildItem). Maybe you and ConnorLSW are right and I should simply use Tee-Object to store the objects in a variable and "massage" these (using Group-Object etc.) to fit my needs. Thanks again to both of you!

Comment: _used to fundamentally change the appearance of the output_. Yes. Much in the same way that Format-Table and Format-List work. While you can hide and show certain columns with those cmdlets they do not manipulate data in the way you desire but define how and what is shown in console. if you want to see if other more experienced have other thoughts on this matter I would edit your title to deal with formatting files specifically since your title made me think you wanted something different.

Comment: @Matt You are probably aware that the lay-out of the PowerShell help topics is also done using formatting. Custom views can really transform cmdlet output beyond recognition (but perhaps not as substantially as what I'm looking for...) ;-)

Comment: Yes. _I do not think_ they are capable of grouping (how you need it) and transpositions though with dynamic columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell format files aren't going to help you here.  The format files determine, for example, which fields display and their order when you run `Get-ChildItem` or `Get-Process`.  What you're doing here is a dynamic transform.  In SQL, this operation is known as a PIVOT.  PIVOTs are usually a pain -- dynamic PIVOTs doubly so -- because they fundamentally transform data.  You're going to have to do it manually.

That said, it's not really difficult to do:

```
$Data = [PSCustomObject]@{Type = 'Foo'; ID = 1; Status = 'Active'  },
[PSCustomObject]@{Type = 'Foo'; ID = 3; Status = 'Active'  },
[PSCustomObject]@{Type = 'Baz'; ID = 1; Status = 'Inactive'},
[PSCustomObject]@{Type = 'Baz'; ID = 2; Status = 'Active'  },
[PSCustomObject]@{Type = 'Baz'; ID = 3; Status = 'Broken'  },
[PSCustomObject]@{Type = 'Bar'; ID = 4; Status = 'Active'  }

function Get-PivotedObject {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        $Data,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$Entity,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$Attribute,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$Value
    )

    $PivotHeaders = $Data | Select-Object -ExpandProperty $Attribute -Unique;

    $Data | Select-Object -ExpandProperty $Entity -Unique | ForEach-Object {
        $Record = [ordered]@{
            $Entity = $_;
        }
        foreach ($Header in $PivotHeaders) {
            $Record.$Header = $Data | Where-Object { 
                ($_.$Entity -eq $Record.$Entity) -and ($_.$Attribute -eq $Header)
            } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty $Value -First 1;
            # Notice this only returns the first value it finds for a given entity and attribute

        }

        [PSCustomObject]$Record;
    }
}

Get-PivotedObject -Data $Data -Entity 'ID' -Attribute 'Type' -Value 'Status'
```

Comment: Too bad this effect cannot be achieved "natively", but it's good to have a nice, generic work-around! :-)